# Rhinoslider not working "Effect for explode not found"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Im trying to use the awesome [jQuery Rhinoslider plugin](http://rhinoslider.com), however it does not work one bit.

Not even the demo i downloaded works, it just throws `Effect for explode not found` and "Preparations for explode not found" in the console.
I choose the effect `explode` but this happens with every effect, even if i choose `none` as effect.
The documentation is pretty poor regarding this kind of questions and you dont find a lot of answers on the internet for this plugin..
Does anybody know what this logs mean? I included every other scripts (easing, mousewheel) and as said, not even the demo i downloaded is working.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need explode effect from [jqueryUI download page](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unluckily that was not the solution, i downloaded and included it and it didnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "Effect not found" issue and I solved it with downloading again the slider from http://rhinoslider.com/demo-download/ 
You may need to check all the effects or the effects you need, because they are not checked by default.